# Building an app with group messaging feature. Suggestions?

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, messaging

without getting into too many details, I would like to build an app capable of messaging between small groups of people. Basically, I need an API that will allow me to a) create a group message, and b) will allow me to later add people to it based on their selections from the application itself. I am relatively new to server side coding and am looking for some suggestions, tutorials, suggested apis (google hangouts vs facebook vs any other services that would be of use), etc. I already have google plus integration with the client side and server side authentication, so it seems like if something is possible with hangouts that would be the easiest route, but again I am just looking for anything really at this point.

The way I was kind of (hoping) it would work is that some messaging service provides the group chat and gives me an ID to it, which I could then have the clients request to be added to a particular chat and then I pass them back the ID to the chat and it begins an intent that takes them to the app itself that is hosting the chat between my users. Let me know if this is possible please, along with any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try researching the ejabberd messaging server. It is probably going to be a bit heavy for your needs as well as difficult to learn (it is in Erlang) but I've found it extremely steady as a back-end for building a messaging server.